# How to set backButton text to empty?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I tried this code:

```
navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""
```

but it does not work and did not change anything. How can I set backButton text to empty?

Answer (score 11):

I tried this code for back button title. and it's work correctly

```
 let barButton = UIBarButtonItem()
 barButton.title = ""
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Answer (score 6):

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = ""
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

for see just **<** instead of **< viewController**

Comment: Grazie! A simple solution in swift :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the previous controller's title, try doing so before the segue in the viewDidDisappear

Answer (score 1):

To remove the `backButtonItem`'s title, place this line of code in the `viewDidLoad:` of the `View Controller` that the `backButtonItem` is in:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, 
target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=nil;
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a difference between these two ?