# Trying to remove backBarButtonItem's title

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to remove the title of the `backBarButtonItem` which has the title of the previous `ViewController`. This is what I am getting now.

[image]

I am trying to make it like this.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set backButton text to empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288419/how-to-set-backbutton-text-to-empty)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UINavigationBar Hide back Button Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853617/uinavigationbar-hide-back-button-text)

Comment: are you using Storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `First` viewController call:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Comment: thank you very much. this works like a charm. not quite sure how though. could you please explain.

Comment: Yes, the backBarButtonItem property of the navigationItem is the button used to go back to the current viewController, so you have to set it in the first viewController in order to remove the title in the second. You can see the full doc here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624958-backbarbuttonitem

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. You can try -

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""
```